# Microsoft Graph. Access OneDrive with application own identity

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

In a mobile application we are generating some images that we would like to upload to the client's cloud.
The client is using OneDrive For Business, with all the 360 suite (I have no more information about it yet).

What we would like to do, is to be able to store the images in a OneDrive account, without the user having to sign in. All the documentation I found to authenticate to OneDrive includes an interactive sign-in process which we don't want:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/graph-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online

I have found that for Microsoft Graph there is the possibility of using the app's  own identity to sign in (only REST), but it is not 100% clear to me that this authentication can grant access to OneDrive. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service

Since I am not familiar at all with Microsoft cloud infrastructure I would appreciate some info.

Is it actually possible to access a OneDrive folder authenticating with the app's own identity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it should be possible to work with Microsoft Graph API and One drive files using application identity (i.e. without a user sign-in)

**REST API's that should help**

Do know that there are many SDK's/Client Libraries available for Microsoft Graph API that you can work with depending on your platform. e.g. [Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet). As you've mentioned Only REST, I'm giving links for direct REST APIs here.

1. Uploading files (upto 4 MB) - [Upload REST API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AF04.png)

   Least permission required will be `Files.ReadWrite.All` (under application permissions and Admin consent will be required first for this application permission. In case you aren't familiar with consent process, take a look here: [Azure AD Consent Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/consent-framework) and mention in comments, I can add a little more detail if needed)

   [image]
2. Uploading larger files - [Resumable Upload REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0)

   [image]

**Authentication**

From a flow standpoint you will need to make use of **[OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Grant Flow to authenticate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow)**

**NOTE**: Please do note that this flow is meant only for confidential clients. So you shouldn't make use of it directly from a mobile client or even desktop client (like WPF or console application), as these are public clients which can not securely handle client secrets. Your mobile client should call a backend API, that in turn can call Microsoft Graph and uses client secrets, acting like a daemon using Application permissions.

At the end of this link there are code samples available for .NET Core 2.1 and ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Using the client credential flow directly from a mobile app is not a good idea. The App Id and Secret would need to be included in the application and therefore prone to being found through inspection.  App Only aka client credential flow should only be used where you can secure the app secret. An example of that would be in an API that interacts with OneDrive and your mobile app calls that API. Then you can comfortably change the secret when it expires etc...

Comment: That's a fair point @ChrisJohnson using client credentials flow (clientid and secret) directly from mobile client app or any native app (even desktop console) would be an issue as it's only meant for Confidential Clients that can handle secrets securely. I answered focusing at the last line in question, that is it possible. My bad, I should clarify that if planning to use a mobile client app to call directly, you should use a backend API (your own server based API) that supports the mobile client and uses this flow to work with Microsoft Graph.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson I have updated the answer to include this. Thanks a lot for noticing and pointing it out.